# Undetermined Coeficient problem using Wolfram Alpha

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I ran this ecuation through Wolfram Alpha:

y''+3y'+2y = 1/(1+e^x)

Everyone in the internet agrees the answer is the one Wolfram Alpha Provides, including my teacher.

However while using Variation of Parameters, I reach this point where:

Yp = U1*Y1+U2*Y2

U1: ln(e^(x)+1)

U2: ln(e^(x)+1)-e^(x)

y1 = e^(-x)

y2 = e^(-2x)

And Wolfram does too!!!

Even tho Wolfram and I reach the same point, wolfram does something absolutely strange for me, I wanna understand what it does and where the heck does the extra "-e^(x)" go. I just don't get it... how can both of the values I drew a circle around on the image can posibly be the same?

[Wolfram Strange Proceadure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZhlc.gif)

EDIT: when I run the Yp proceadure i wrote above in my voyage 200, I get:

e^(-2x)*((e^(x)+1)+ln(e^(x)+1) - e^x)

Is it correct?

Comment: The "missing" term got absorbed into one of the constants.

Comment: Please Explain, I'm not that "gifted" in mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular solution is:

$$y(x) = \frac{-e^x + \log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}}$$

We can separate out the terms as :

$$y(x) = \frac{-e^x}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}}$$

Now, the first term (which is our "extra" term) is

$$\frac{-e^x}{e^{2x}} = \frac{-(e^x)}{(e^x)^2} = \frac{-1}{e^x}$$

So that when we have our general solution, we can rewrite it as

$$\begin{align}y(x) &= \frac{-e^x+\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}} + \frac{c_1}{e^{2x}} + \frac{c_2}{e^x}\\
&= \frac{-e^x}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}} + \frac{c_1}{e^{2x}} + \frac{c_2}{e^x}\\
&= \underbrace{\frac{-1}{e^{x}}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}} + \frac{c_1}{e^{2x}} + \underbrace{\frac{c_2}{e^x}}\\
&= \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}} + \frac{c_1}{e^{2x}} + \underbrace{\frac{c_2-1}{e^x}}\\
&= \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{2x}} + \frac{\log{(e^x + 1)}}{e^{x}} + \frac{c_1}{e^{2x}} + \underbrace{\frac{c_2^{\star}}{e^x}}\\
\end{align} $$

where in the end we introduce a new arbitrary constant $c_2^\star \equiv c_2 - 1$.